# Prepared statement for login function PHP

Tags: php, function, authentication, prepared-statement

I am trying to write a parametrised login function in PHP. 
The function should get the $id and $pass bind and execute statement and return an associative array from the database with $id, $password, $user_first_name.
Checking for user id and password validation, if true the session should start and set the session with the username from the database.
For some reason I can't get this working. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
public function logIn($id, $password)

            {
                $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_password FROM Users WHERE user_id = ? ");
                $stms->bind_param('i', $user_id);
                if ($stmt->execute())
                {
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                        { 
                        $dbuser_id = $row['user_id'];
                        $dbpassword = $row['user_password'];
                        $dbuser_first_name = $row['user_first_name'];
                        }


                        if($id == $dbuser_id and $password == $dbpassword)
                        {
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['session_user_first_name'] = $dbuser_first_name;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            session_unset();
                            echo "Credentials do not match";
                        }
                }   

            }
```

Comment: Check your viariable $stms->bind_param('i', $user_id);  replace $user_id by $id

Comment: `$stms->` that's wrong. You start off with `$stmt = $this->link->prepare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
$stms->bind_param('i', $user_id);
```

But your function signature is:

```
public function logIn($id, $password)
```

So you probably want:

```
$stms->bind_param('i', $id);
```

Comment: Silly mistakes... still won't work. I am thinking how I am getting the data from the assoc. array maybe is not right....

Comment: Got it working now. I just did silly mistake in not calling the right name from the database for user. user_first_name instead of user_name. Thanks anyway for the other typing corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `$stms->bind_param('i', $user_id);`:

- `stms` should be `stmt`
- `$user_id` should be `$id`
- ...